# Previous Login Art

Tags: league-of-legends

I started to play recently, and I enjoyed seeing the animated login screens for Syndra, Rengar, and Kha'Zix.

Is there a way to view animated login screens for previous champions?

Comment: Just an FYI, this is pretty new. Pulsefire Ezreal was either the first or 2nd, I believe.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Did Draven come before Pulsefire?

Comment: I dont' know about animated but i know where to find the stills.... would that answer the question?

Comment: @Fluttershy I dunno. But I know Darius had one, and he came before Draven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Riot now uploads login screens to YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbAFXJC0J5GZHUtGea_zQR0OyD3UBuw9s) (Finally!)

As of writing, this is missing those from before the Hecarim patch. You can find them here:

1. [League of Legends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOBlLRTcjJU)
2. [Christmas 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YSDGkcEnto)
3. [Lunar Revel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxoZSU3FQfA)
4. [Lulu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLSRe2oFwg0)

Older instructions below, and in revision history.

---

You can find the files yourself on your hard drive.

First, locate the folder of the login screen you want. You can find them all in the folder:

```
C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\#\deploy\mod\lgn\themes\
```

where `#` is a number like `0.0.1.138` that may change from time to time. (If there are multiple such numbers, select the newest folder.)

Once you've found the theme, you'll find several files and folders:

- `cs_bg_champions.png` is the image that will be displayed if you disable animation.
- `flv/` contains the animations.
- `music/` contains the music.

---

If you don't have a specific theme on your hard drive, you can use a tool like [LoL Summoner Information](http://leaguelsi.com/) to download (and switch) them. Open the tool, then go to *Client utilities* → *Login screen*, then click on options in the list to download them.

Comment: This answer previously included various YouTube links to the screens. This was unmaintainable, so I've edited them out; you may find them in the revision history.

Answer (score 3):

While I know the question originally asked for the log in *screens*, I have found copies of most (all?) of the login screen *music*, [hosted on the official League of Legends Soundcloud account.](https://soundcloud.com/leagueoflegends)

These can all be downloaded as mp3s, and (perhaps relevantly), they are not the looping versions of the songs that the actual launcher uses.

Answer (score 2):

Since I stumbled over this question, I'd consider it important to mention that the paths to the files in the client changed some time last year.

The different login screens are now considered "mods" and can be found in the following folder:

```
[Install location of League of Legends]\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\#.#.#.#\deploy\mod\lgn\themes
```

There'll be one sub folder per theme, for example right now there's **loginBraum**. These will be removed/updated with future patches.

In there you'll find a **Shockwave Flash** file with the actual animation/intro, as well as a sub folder **music** with two mp3 files (intro and looping).